# How to pd.concat dataframes with respect to column-values instead of an index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a dataframe of metadata represented as `DF_0` and then a dataframe of actual data (`DF_1`).  I want to use `pd.concat` on my dataframes but not with respect to indices. The indices of `DF_0` are arbitrary and the indices of `DF_1` correspond to the values in `attr_1` of `DF_0`.

The only ways I could think of doing it were:

(1) to make `attr_1` my index then merge which I'd rather not do; or

(2) sort and then merge [but missing data might mess this up].  I feel like `pandas` has thought of this.

**Does anyone know of a way to use `pd.concat` or something similar [my real data has strings, floats, ints] to merge 2 [or more?] dataframes along the "axis" represented by the values of a particular column in a particular dataframe?**

The values may or not be in order.  Are the ways I described above the only ways? They seem messy...

```
DF_0 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(5,3), 
                    columns=["attr_%d"%j for j in range(3)])
#    attr_0  attr_1  attr_2
# 0       0       1       2
# 1       3       4       5
# 2       6       7       8
# 3       9      10      11
# 4      12      13      14

DF_1 = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,1]], 
                     index = ["other_%d"%j for j in range(3)], 
                     columns = [1,4,7,10,13]).T
#     other_0  other_1  other_2
# 1         0        0        1
# 4         1        0        1
# 7         0        0        1
# 10        1        1        0
# 13        1        0        1

# What I want
DF_X = pd.DataFrame(
                    np.concatenate([DF_0.as_matrix(), DF_1.as_matrix()], axis=1), 
                    columns=list(DF_0.columns) + list(DF_1.columns))
#    attr_0  attr_1  attr_2  other_0  other_1  other_2
# 0       0       1       2        0        0        1
# 1       3       4       5        1        0        1
# 2       6       7       8        0        0        1
# 3       9      10      11        1        1        0
# 4      12      13      14        1        0        1
```

Comment: try this: `pd.concat([...], axis=1)`

Comment: The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) show that there is a `axis` param to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to merge along the `attr_1` column of `DF_0` and the index of `DF_1`:

```
DF_X = pd.merge(DF_0, DF_1, left_on='attr_1', right_index=True)
print(DF_X)
```

Output:

```
   attr_0  attr_1  attr_2  other_0  other_1  other_2
0       0       1       2        0        0        1
1       3       4       5        1        0        1
2       6       7       8        0        0        1
3       9      10      11        1        1        0
4      12      13      14        1        0        1
```

Comment: that was exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for `axis=1` parameter of the [concat()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) method.

[Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) is a good explanation with examples of different types of joining / merging / concatenating 
Demo:

```
In [6]: pd.concat([DF_0, DF_1], axis=1)
Out[6]:
   attr_0  attr_1  attr_2  other_0  other_1  other_2  other_3
0       0       1       2        1        0        0        1
1       3       4       5        4        1        0        1
2       6       7       8        7        0        0        1
3       9      10      11       10        1        1        0
4      12      13      14       13        1        0        1
```

Comment: They would need to have the same indices for this, right?

Comment: @O.rka, yes - all DFs will be merged by indices

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't with `pd.concat` its with understanding what you want. You can clear this up by thinking through what the final result should look like given the samples you've shown `DF_0` and `DF_1`.

If `attr_1` is the same as `DF_1`s index then:

```
pd.concat([DF_0.set_index('attr_1', drop=False), DF_1], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This is a good way too but I was trying to see if there was a way w/o merging indices.